# Can i create an .msm using wix and nant

Tags: wix, nant

Can i create an .msm using wix and nant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at the [Module](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_module.htm) element and use the same set of tools you do to build MSI package.